# Unitarily invariant matrix norm

Tags: matrices

Let A, B ∈ Mn. If the product AB is hermitian, show that ||AB|| ≤ ||BA|| for any unitarily invariant matrix-vector norm || · ||.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Presumably the so-called "matrix-vector" norm means a matrix norm induced from a vector norm.)*

It is known that $\|X\|\ge\|Y\|$ for every unitarily invariant norm if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^k\sigma_i(X)\ge\sum_{i=1}^k\sigma_i(Y)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ (cf. corollary 7.4.47 of Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, 1st edition, pp.447).

Note that $AB$ unitarily diagonalisable and $BA$ is a unitarily triangulable matrix that has the same spectrum as $AB$. The problem therefore reduces to proving that $\|D\|\le\|R\|$ for any unitarily invariant norm, where $D$ is a real diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are arranged with descending magnitudes and $R$ is an upper triangular matrix with the same diagonal as $D$. As $\|SD\|=\|D\|$ and $\|SR\|=\|R\|$ for every diagonal matrix $S$ whose diagonal entries are $\pm1$, we may further assume that the common diagonals of $D$ and $R$ are nonnegative real numbers arranged in descending order. It follows that for each $k=1,2,\ldots,n$,
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^k\sigma_i(R)
&=\max\left\{\left|\sum_{i=1}^ku_i^\ast Ru_i\right|: \{u_1,\ldots,u_k\} \text{ is a set of orthonormal vectors}\right\}\\
&\ge\left|\sum_{i=1}^kr_{ii}\right|
=\sum_{i=1}^kd_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^k\sigma_i(D).
\end{aligned}
Now we are done.